# Is it possible to connect Karate automation framework with Dynamo Database from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, automation, amazon-dynamodb, karate

I would like to know how to make a connection between Karate testing automation framework and AWS' DynamoDB.

I've researched a lot, but without success.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?